# Why am I unable to change my DNS settings?

Tags: windows-7, dns

Accessing internet through vodafon mobile stick on single PC. I want to change the DNS to Google to speed up my connection.

For this disconnected the connection and changed DNS settings in adapter settings dialogue.

But as soon as I reconnect the "Use the following server address" area gets clear and the default DNS settings is applied. So, How can I keep the settings unchanged to Google DNS?

Comment: How are you connecting? are you using the Vodafone dialer or the windows dialer?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer to your problem, but it's a workaround.

You could create a batch file (`.bat`) using notepad, with the following command in it. This will set the DNS for the specified network adapter. Just run it everytime you connect.

> Netsh interface ip set dns name="[connectionname]" source="static" address="x.x.x.x"

*Example:*

> Netsh interface ip set dns name="Wireless Network Connection" source="static" address="8.8.8.8"

***NB:***
Make sure you run the batch file as administrator on Windows 7:

[image]

## * Edit *

By the way, if you're not located in the US some would recommend you don't use google's public DNS as your default, for a number of reasons.